# Can't set Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 card power on laptop under Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, power-management, powertop

I've been trying to set the power management on my wireless card.  I looked at PowerTOP and I tried setting power management on the wireless card, but it doesn't work.  When I tried using the command provided by PowerTOP, `iw dev wlan0 set power_save on`, it gives me the error, "command failed: Operation not supported (-95)."  I have also tried the command `iwconfig wlan0 power saving 3`, but that gave me the error:

```
"Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
   SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

So my guess is that it isn't supported at the moment?  If anyone's wondering, I'm using Elementary OS Freya with the 3.13.0-49-generic kernel.  The readout from `lspci -vv` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0208
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at 90400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at 90480000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA    PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported- RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+ ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
            Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
            Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1- EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover- Timeout+ NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I figured it out.

What I did was add `ath9k.ps_enable=1` to my boot-up options.  I am now able to use the command `iw dev wlan0 set power_save on`.

I found the answer on this [website](http://www.overclock.net/t/1475054/cant-enable-power-saving-on-atheros-ar9485).

Answer (score 0):

Per that lspci it IS supported however I would Highly  recommend getting on a newer kernel a 3.13 is known buggy

While I run the 4.0 on Fedora personally ,  3.16.x & 3.17.x  are Really stable and SHOULD have all the support  needed natively built in...

Comment: Ah, crap. I'm currently using the stable version of the OS, and they don't supply a 3.16 nor a 3.17 kernel. :-/